# Complex AQA A-Level Comp4 Computing project

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net

I have an unusually large A-level class this year and a lot of students who are struggling to come up with complex programming projects.

The students are college level (17-18) and have experience with vb.net, mysql and php... we are trying to shy away from database projects though (issues with the school networks).

Would anyone have some good ideas I could pass their way, part of the catch is that the projects must have a real end user... a typical A* project might be a simulation of gas laws.

Thanks,

D Stephenson

Comment: Anything statistics analysis would work great.  Take a look at the data dump netflix posted a couple of years ago and they posted a public challenge for improved auto recommendation based off viewing habits of users. Now to really get into it you're well outside of alevel but you could do basic mean/average/deviation/normal based recommendations which is pretty much alevel class.  Alternatively you could do something like projectile calculation given input barrel length, calibre, gravity, force etc you can calculate the distance, arc etc then factor in wind force.

Comment: Not sure if this is the right forum (in the old-fashioned sense of the word) for this, but I like it, so I plus-oned it anyway. I suggest you tweet Ben Goldacre. He's always suggesting projects for budding programmers.